# Put a save button in the middle of the form

Tags: button, extjs, layout, alignment

I have a form with two textfields which are aligned in 'vbox' format with align as 'stretch'. I wish to now add a SAVE button which should be aligned in the middle of the form. How do I define this button to be exactly aligned in the middle just like in a usual alert where the OK button is in the middle of the alert box.

If it can be done without CSSS then that would be preferable.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[buttonAlign](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-buttonAlign) : The alignment of any buttons added to this panel. Valid values are 'right', 'left' and 'center' (defaults to 'right' for buttons/fbar, 'left' for other toolbar types).*

Another way is to use dockedItems with layout:'hbox' and pack:'center'

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            width: 300,
            bodyPadding: 10,
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                title: 'Contact Info',
                name: 'name',
                fieldLabel: 'Name'
            }, {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'email',
                fieldLabel: 'Email Address'
            }],

            buttons: [{
                text: 'Save'
            }],
            buttonAlign: 'center',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        })
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/npl)

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for the answer. This solves my problem. One follow up though. I am using ExtJS 4. The bottom toolbar for buttons comes out to be transparent. It contains a button and the rest of the area is transparent (see through). Is there any way to make it solid and not see through?

Comment: @aayush_v20 Can you post a screenshot or some code?

Comment: I have posted a screenshot of the transparent button toolbar.

Comment: try using dockedItems. Let me see why it's transparent.

Comment: @aayush_v20  I've updated the fiddle - added implementation using dockeditems and also added a config for buttons. Please check

Comment: Can you inspect the element and check why it's transparent?